# Access on NHibernate: slowness?

Tags: database, nhibernate, ms-access

I'm using NHibernate and Microsoft Access. My database file is fairly large ( ~500 MB ) and my app. is slow when writing to the database and I was wondering if any of you have experience with NHibernate and large Access databases. I want to know if this slowness in the app. is an known issue.

Regards,
MadSeb

P.S I did "compact and repair" the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Post comment update**
You are not seeing 'normal slowness', you are seeing long hangs.  I would need to see code / config / database schema / database stats (#of rows in tables, indexes etc) to help any.

**P.S.** 
 500 MB isn't very large, and the times for inserts that you are seeing is not normal.

Comment: when I run an INSERT query from Access , everything works quite well but when run the same operation from C#/NHibernate it can take up to 5 minutes.

Comment: you should put that in your question.  That's more than just slowness. For that we will need code and probably config values.